# python width syntax error

Tags: python, linux, syntax

I am running Ubuntu with python 2.7.2.

script

```
python \
/home/blainer/Desktop/convert/converter.py \
/home/blainer/Desktop/convert/urban.shp \
/home/blainer/Desktop/convert/result.js \
--width 900 \
--country_name_index 4 \
--where "ISO = 'USA'" \
--codes_file /home/blainer/Desktop/convert/codes-en.tsv \
--insets '[{"codes": ["US-AK"], "width": 200, "left": 10, "top": 370}, {"codes": ["US-HI"], "width": 100, "left": 220, "top": 400}]' \
--minimal_area 4000000 \
--buffer_distance -3000 \
--simplify_tolerance 1000 \
--longtitude0 10w \
--name us
```

error

```
blainer@ubuntu:~/Desktop/convert$ python script.py
File "script.py", line 5
--width 900 \
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You don't have any trailing blanks after any of your \ right? What happens if you put everything on a single line up to and including the width parameter, will you get this error too?

Comment: @Levon It's not a Python script at all, and he's trying to run it with Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not a Python script, it's a shell script that runs Python.

1. Name it `script.sh`, not `.py`.
2. Add a "shebang" line to the top: `#!/bin/bash`
3. Make it executable: `chmod +x ./script.sh`
4. Run it: `blainer@ubuntu:~/Desktop/convert$ ./script.sh`

Comment: I have to start typing it as "sh-bang" otherwise every time I think of William Hung singing "She Bangs"